# have a batch file read a text file from dropbox and execute it as variables in the batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a batch to file read a text file from dropbox and execute it as variables in the batch file.

this is what i am trying, but it does not work, please help!

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set content=

for /F "delims=" %%i in (DROPBOX-LINK-HERE) do set content=!

content! %%i

%content%
EndLocal
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand well what you are trying to do. Could you please post a sample of the text file and then specify what you would expect as the result of the execution of this batch script?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by `DROPBOX-LINK-HERE`, but I am using an ordinary text file for content.

You must separate each line with `&` or else enclose the content in parentheses and separate each line with `<linefeed>`. The linefeed solution is more complicated, but has fewer limitations on the content.

Any `!` characters in the content will be corrupted during expansion of a FOR variable if delayed expansion is enabled. But delayed expansion is needed to preserve unquoted special characters. So delayed expansion needs to be creatively toggled on and off.

Here is code that I think does what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

::Define a carriage return variable
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

::Create a newline variable
set LF=^


::The above 2 blank lines are critical - do not remove

::Both CR and LF should be expanded using delayed expansion only.

::Load the content into a variable.
::We want to separate lines with linefeed, but FOR /F won't preserve linefeeds.
::So use carriage return as a place holder for now.
set "content=("
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%C in ("!CR! ") do (
  endlocal
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (test.txt) do (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("!content!") do (
      endlocal
      set "content=%%B%%C%%A"
    )
  )
)

::Now replace carriage returns with newline and append terminating )
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%C in ("!CR! ") do for %%N in ("!LF!") do set "content=!content:%%C=%%~N!%%~N)"

::Execute the content
endlocal&%content%
```

The code works, but there are limitations to the type of code that can be executed from a variable.

- Variables cannot be expanded by using normal expansion unless you use CALL. For example, a line like `echo %var%` will not work, but `call echo %var%` will work. Another option is to use delayed expansion. `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `ENDLOCAL` can be included in the content as needed.
- You cannot `CALL` or `GOTO` a `:LABEL` within the content.

That's all I can remember at the moment, but there may be (probably are) other restrictions.

I have one question though:

***If the content is already in a text file, then why not simply give the text file a .BAT extension and execute it?***

Comment: +1 (As always) Sometimes there really exists simple soultions :-) `why not simply give the text file a .BAT extension and execute it?`. But your solution is much more advanced...